# How are simple textures like this made?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, patterns

I've realized that simple textures like the one used on this site:

[image]

..add a lot to the look of a page. How are they made though? I'm not very experienced in Photoshop, but I can't imagine what tool would be used to make the random specs across the pattern.

Comment: http://creativebits.org/photoshop/scan_line_effect_in_photoshop & http://www.tutorialsbucket.com/noise-texture-background-effect-in-adobe-photoshop-cs5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top part, which contains the darker blue stripes, was most likely made using a background color and a **pattern overlay** (a part that repeats itself along the image, making it look like it was put together nicely).

I couldn't hardly notice the specs you mentioned, but it's quite easy to add "noise" in Photoshop using the **noise filter**. It does exactly what you would expect it to.

There could also be a little shadow effect for the top part, adding some depth to it.